# Using output of summarise() in R

Tags: r, dplyr

How do I use the output of the summarise() in R. I know it creates a table, but I can't seem to use it for further calculations.
I'm trying to calculate the margin of error for a sample proportion.

```
us_pro <- us12 %>%
   summarise(us_prop=sum(response == "atheist")/sum(response == "atheist" | response == "non-atheist"), n=n()) %>%
    as.data.frame()


us_pro %>%
  me_perc=qnorm(0.975)*sqrt(us_prop*(1-us_prop)/n)
```

The ME calculation errors out with

> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'us_prop' not found Calls:
>    ... handle -> withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval
>   -> eval Execution halted

I'm guessing it's a very basic error, but i can't understand what

Comment: This has nothing to do with `summarize`. The problem is that you aren't *continuing* to use `dplyr` functions.  When you do `us_pro %>%`, your next line is `me_perc = qnorm(...)`, but you need to pipe `us_pro` into a function, like `mutate` or `summarize`. Make it `us_pro %>% mutate(me_perc = qnorm(...))`.

Comment: Thank. Understood what I was doing wrong.
`us_pro %>%
  mutate(me_per = 100*qnorm(0.975)*sqrt(us_prop*(1-us_prop)/n))`

Alternately, I should have been doing this I guess,
`try_perc=100*qnorm(0.975)*sqrt(us_pro$us_prop*(1-us_pro$us_prop)/us_pro$n)
try_perc`

Comment: Right, depends whether you want `try_perc` as a separate variable or as a column of your data frame.

Comment: As an aside, if you want `try_perc` as a separate object but don't want to type `us_pro$` multiple times, you can use the base R `with` utility: `me_perc =  with(us_pro, qnorm(0.975)*sqrt(us_prop*(1-us_prop)/n))`